# why can't I change the height of the box?

Tags: css, height

i'm trying to create a responsive photo gallery but I couldn't change neither the height or the width of my box.

I was able to fix its width adding style property to the html but it won't work for the height as well.

I've read many thread about the height problem but nothing works for me, some suggested the absolute position instead of relative one but it ruins my layout.
Can't seem to get what i am doing wrong, could anyone help me please?!

Here's my code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: #203B5B;
  padding: 1% 1% 0% 1%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
}

.box {
  margin-top: 0%;
  height: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 90%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 55;
  width: 50%;
  height: 72.5%;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
}

.box:hover::after {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}

.container .box .caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 60;
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  -moz-transform: scale(3);
  -ms-transform: scale(3);
  -o-transform: scale(3);
  transform: scale(3);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
  font: 90% montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box:hover .caption {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: scale(1) translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: scale(1) translate(0%, -50%);
  -o-transform: scale(1) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: scale(1) translate(0%, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.86);
  border-width: 3.5px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: 5px;
  outline-color: #182D46;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 37%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 95%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 50;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
}

.box:hover img {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%;">
    <div class="caption">1</div>
    <a href=""><img src="1.jpg" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%;">
    <div class="caption">2</div>
    <a href=""><img src="2.png" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%; ">
    <div class="caption">3</div>
    <a href="NAM.html"><img src="3.jpg" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%">
    <div class="caption">4</div>
    <a href=""><img src="4.png" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%">
    <div class="caption">5</div>
    <a href=""><img src="5.png" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%">
    <div class="caption">6</div>
    <a href=""><img src="6.png" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="width:14.6%">
    <div class="caption">7</div>
    <a href="Titti Smeriglio.html"><img src="7.png" width="495" height="533" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you!

Comment: there is no need to exhibit so many lines of code for such a question, make it minimal, you have to read => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hello whats the final result you want

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the width and height for your `box` div in percentages, it is taking x% of the parent. In this case the `container` div. Which in this case also got its width and height set in percentages. But you haven't set a width and height for its parent, the `<body>`. And the `<body>` has `<html>` as its parent.

So either define a fixed height and width for the `container` div, or define a width and height for your `<body>` and `<html>` like so:

```
html, 
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Code snippet**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: #203B5B;
  padding: 1% 1% 0% 1%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 14.25%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box img {
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.86);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">1</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">2</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">3</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">4</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">5</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">6</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="caption">7</div>
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.